# Weird behaviour of Qt Signals/Slots (involving dynamically loaded DLL)

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I have a program that **dynamically** loads a **`.dll`** and I want to connect several **signals** of that **`.dll`** with **slots** of my program. More precisely I want to call a certain function that emits those signals. However **only a few** of these signals are actually invoking their corresponding slot in my program. The others just **do nothing**. But if I emit the signal directly and not through the function I mentioned the connected slots are invoked. The following code tries to illustrate what I mean:

**Connection setup**

```cpp
DLLClass * dll_ptr;        // pointer to dynamically loaded DLL-class
ProgClass * prog_ptr;      // pointer to a class of my program
connect(dll_ptr, &DLLClass::sigA, prog_ptr, &ProgClass::slotA, Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(dll_ptr, &DLLClass::sigB, prog_ptr, &ProgClass::slotB, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

**Certain function in .dll**

```cpp
DLLClass::function(){
    emit sigA();
    emit sigB();
}
```

**Code of my program**

```cpp
dll_ptr->function();        // invokes only slotA
emit dll_ptr->sigA();       // invokes slotA
emit dll_ptr->sigB();       // invokes slotB
```

**Additional info**

Some of these signals/slots pass arguments of custom types that are registered via `qRegisterMetaType`.
In another program that also dynamically loads the .dll everything works perfectly fine.

**Question**

Why do some of the emitted signals in my `function()` call fail to invoke their corresponding slot when a direct emission works fine?

Comment: decorate your code with logs `qDebug() << "Some useful info";` to make sure that signal is actually invoked. How do you link standard library in app and in DLL? How do you link Qt?

Comment: What do slots signatures look like? You don't check *connect* return code. Take a look at [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Strangley the problem does not persist anymore since I did a rebuild (and a change of the startup project in my dll-creating VS solution). If it returns I will check out the `qDebug` info. The `connects` all returned `true`. Thank you for your input!